# How to get the column labels to display?

Tags: visualforce

In this VF page, only the year__c column has a label showing. The other columns don't show a label. How to get the columns to show labels? (see pic for a visual)[image]

```
[![<apex:page standardController="Community_Yearly_Plan__c" extensions="vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr" cache="false">

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Community Plan Setting Goals" columns="1" id="pbsCon" >
                <apex:outputPanel id="panelCon">
                    <div id="loading-curtain-div"/>

                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtCon" value="{!listGoalsCurrYear}" var="cpgs">

                        <apex:column value="{!cpgs.Year__c}" />                        
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:inputField id="ft" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Type__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True' || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:inputField id="ccp" value="{!cpgs.Core_Current_Participation__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True'  || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   

                        <apex:column style="width:10px;">
                            <apex:inputField id="fa" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True' || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:inputField id="fd" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Description__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True' || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column style="width:10px;">
                            <apex:inputField id="ga" value="{!cpgs.Goal_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True' || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:inputField id="gac" value="{!cpgs.Goal_Amount_Comments__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.EditableOrReadOnly__c='True' || newRow ="nr",'True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                    <apex:commandButton style="align:center;" action="{!AddRow}" value="Add Funding Record" reRender="pbsCon" />
                    <apex:commandButton style="align:center;" action="{!SaveRecords}" value="Save" reRender="pbsCon" />                    

                </apex:outputPanel>

                <apex:outputPanel id="panelCon2">
                    <div id="loading-curtain-div"/>

                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtCon2" value="{!listGoalsPrevYears}" var="cpgs2">

                        <apex:column value="{!cpgs2.Year__c}" />                        
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Type__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Core_Current_Participation__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Description__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Goal_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Goal_Amount_Comments__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                </apex:outputPanel>                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you specify the `value` attribute of a column to be an SObject field, the component automatically creates the header label.

From https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_column.htm

> Note that if you specify an sObject field as the value attribute for
>   an <apex:column>, the associated label for that field is used as the
>   column header by default.

Where you are creating your own custom column contents, you need to use the header facet to specify your header:

```
<apex:column style="text-align:center">
    <apex:facet name="header">Label</apex:facet> 
    <apex:inputField .... />
</apex:column>
```